# Why is Compass/Scss setting list-style: none by default?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

It seems like my scss is turning off ordered list styles by default, which seems a little strange / annoying. Can anyone explain why it would do that?

This is the line that was mysteriously added to my css:

```
/* line 24, C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

A little splunking showed that was the result of these lines in the _utilities.scss file:

```
  ol, ul {
    @include reset-list-style; }

// Reset the list style of an element.
@mixin reset-list-style {
  list-style: none; }
```

I'm fixing this issue by adding:

```
ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

to my scss file. Would it be better to modify the _utilities.scss file? It sounds like if I did that it might screw up how scss translates into css for ol, ul elements?

Comment: Also seems weird that I can't add the `scss` tag to this question.

Comment: The `scss` tag is a synonym for `sass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like this behavior, you can take out the reset that's included with Compass. When you start a new compass project, it generates screen.scss with the following:

```
/* Welcome to Compass.
 * In this file you should write your main styles. (or centralize your imports)
 * Import this file using the following HTML or equivalent:
 * <link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> */

@import "compass/reset";
```

Just remove or comment out the @import "compass/reset" and use a reset that's to your liking or use something like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to standardize styles.

Comment: I'm already using Bootstrap, though, and I'm importing bootstrap after my scss-generated css file. Can I just remove all reset files entirely? I don't really need them if I'm using bootstrap, do I?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with bootstrap but I think you could just remove it. They use [normalize.css](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-normalize) so I'm really not sure what the reset is doing in there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Compass (as bootstrap) resets the list-style for lists as written here

[compass utilities documentation](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/reset/utilities/)

I think the best practice would be to add the "inverse" reset rule just to your stylesheet, instead of modifying the library, because, in case you are going to change (maybe) the version of your library and forget to patch it again, you will find unexplainable "errors". I would add it to my reset rules.

Comment: This line is already coming from Compass's reset. You'd be effectively resetting a reset if you did this.